# How to add line based on slope and intercept

Tags: python, matplotlib

In R, there is a function called `abline` in which a line can be drawn on a plot based on the specification of the intercept (first argument) and the slope (second argument). For instance,

```
plot(1:10, 1:10)
abline(0, 1)
```

where the line with an intercept of 0 and the slope of 1 spans the entire range of the plot. Is there such a function in Matplotlib?

Comment: No, there's not. It would be a handy function to have. There's `axvline`, `axvspan`, `axhline`, and `axhspan`, which are similar vertical and horizontal functions, but the usual way in matplotlib is to just plot a line at the given slope (which means that you'll eventually zoom beyond it, if you're working interactively.).  The "correct" way of doing it (i.e. so that it's always spans the axis no matter where you zoom) is actually a bit complicated, though the framework (`matplotlib.transforms`) is there.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate... Matlab does not have this function either. On the other hand, R's plots are static (the `base` graphics system for which `abline` exists) so less to worry about there (it's a good and bad thing I suppose).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

A lot of these solutions are focusing on adding a line to the plot that fits the data. Here's a simple solution for adding an arbitrary line to the plot based on a slope and intercept.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np    

def abline(slope, intercept):
    """Plot a line from slope and intercept"""
    axes = plt.gca()
    x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
    y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '--')
```

Comment: I can't believe this functionality isn't included directly in `matplotlib`. It seems like the very, very first thing one might implement if making such a package.

Comment: @ijoseph Welcome to the world of sharing and caring! "Every good work of software starts by scratching a developer's personal itch" - Eric S. Raymond. Go and send pull request to the [Matplotlib project](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib)!

Comment: just a minor point for completeness it needs `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np` at the start of the script.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. I took the liberty to add an answer which modifies your code to ensures that the sloped line does not expand the original plotting area.

Answer (score 45):

As of 2021, in matplotlib 3.3.4, it supports drawing lines with slope value and a point.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.axline((0, 4), slope=3., color='C0', label='by slope')
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(3, 5) 
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 39):

I know this question is a couple years old, but since there is no accepted answer, I'll add what works for me.

You could just plot the values in your graph, and then generate another set of values for the coordinates of the best fit line and plot that over your original graph.  For example, see the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some dummy data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 7, 9]

# Find the slope and intercept of the best fit line
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

# Create a list of values in the best fit line
abline_values = [slope * i + intercept for i in x]

# Plot the best fit line over the actual values
plt.plot(x, y, '--')
plt.plot(x, abline_values, 'b')
plt.title(slope)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 15):

It looks like this feature will be part of version `3.3.0`:

[matplotlib.axes.Axes.axline](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axline.html?highlight=axline#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axline)

You'll be, for example, able to draw a red line through points `(0, 0)` and `(1, 1)` using

```
axline((0, 0), (1, 1), linewidth=4, color='r')
```

Answer (score 12):

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
Y = np.array([1.1,1.9,3.0,4.1,5.2,5.8,7])

scatter (X,Y)
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
plot(X, X*slope + intercept, 'r')
```

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't figure a way to do it without resorting to callbacks, but this seems to work fairly well.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class ABLine2D(plt.Line2D):

    """
    Draw a line based on its slope and y-intercept. Additional arguments are
    passed to the <matplotlib.lines.Line2D> constructor.
    """

    def __init__(self, slope, intercept, *args, **kwargs):

        # get current axes if user has not specified them
        if not 'axes' in kwargs:
            kwargs.update({'axes':plt.gca()})
        ax = kwargs['axes']

        # if unspecified, get the current line color from the axes
        if not ('color' in kwargs or 'c' in kwargs):
            kwargs.update({'color':ax._get_lines.color_cycle.next()})

        # init the line, add it to the axes
        super(ABLine2D, self).__init__([], [], *args, **kwargs)
        self._slope = slope
        self._intercept = intercept
        ax.add_line(self)

        # cache the renderer, draw the line for the first time
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        self._update_lim(None)

        # connect to axis callbacks
        self.axes.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self._update_lim)
        self.axes.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', self._update_lim)

    def _update_lim(self, event):
        """ called whenever axis x/y limits change """
        x = np.array(self.axes.get_xbound())
        y = (self._slope * x) + self._intercept
        self.set_data(x, y)
        self.axes.draw_artist(self)
```

Comment: small improvement: swap the lines:   
ax.figure.canvas.draw()   and   
self._update_lim(None)    
so the plot is actually updated without having to click the window

Comment: @tal At last on my version of matplotlib (1.4.3) it's necessary to render the parent axes at least once before calling `self.axes.draw_artist(self)`, otherwise I get an `AssertionError` on the line `assert self._cachedRenderer is not None` in `Axes.draw_artist`. You could always insert an additional draw after `_update_lim` has been called. I usually initialize the `ABLine` from inside a convenience function that does this for me, rather than instantiating it directly.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose for the case of `(intercept, slope)` of `(0, 1)` the following function could be used and extended to accommodate other slopes and intercepts, but won't readjust if axis limits are changed or autoscale is turned back on.

```
def abline():
    gca = plt.gca()
    gca.set_autoscale_on(False)
    gca.plot(gca.get_xlim(),gca.get_ylim())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(range(10),range(10))
abline()
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Well, if you just want a line that goes from the lower-left corner to the upper-right corner, no matter how you zoom, then you can just do `plt.plot([0,1],[0,1], transform=plt.gca().transAxes)`.  This won't represent a 1 to 1 slope in data coordinates, though, and it will _always_ go from the lower left corner to the upper right, wherever you zoom to...  Like you said, though, a more general `abline` replacement is more difficult for interactive use...

Comment: Ah, this is quite interesting the transAxes. I can imagine that I will be making use of it at some point... (I often have many plots where xlim=ylim, or should be).

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to expand on the answer from David Marx, where we are making sure that the sloped line does not expand over the original plotting area.
Since the x-axis limits are used to calculate the y-data for the sloped line, we need to make sure, that the calculated y-data does not extend the given ymin - ymax range. If it does crop the displayed data.

```
def abline(slope, intercept,**styles):
    """Plot a line from slope and intercept"""

    axes = plt.gca()
    xmin,xmax = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
    ymin,ymax = np.array(axes.get_ylim()) # get also y limits
    x_vals = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,num=1000) #increased sampling (only actually needed for large slopes)
    y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
    locpos = np.where(y_vals<ymax)[0] # if data extends above ymax
    locneg = np.where(y_vals>ymin)[0] # if data extends below ymin
    # select most restricitive condition 
    if len(locpos) >= len(locneg):
        loc = locneg
    else: 
        loc = locpos
    plt.plot(x_vals[loc], y_vals[loc], '--',**styles)
    return y_vals
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible workaround I came up with: suppose I have my intercept coordinates stored as `x_intercept` and `y_intercept`, and the slope (***m***) saved as `my_slope` which was found through the renowned equation ***m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)***, or in whichever way you managed to find it.

Using the other famous general equation for a line ***y = mx + q***, I define the function `find_second_point` that first computes the ***q*** (since **m**, **x** and **y** are known) and then computes another random point that belongs to that line.

Once I have the two points (the initial `x_intercept`,`y_intercept` and the newly found `new_x`,`new_y`), I simply plot the segment through those two points. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_intercept = 3  # invented x coordinate
y_intercept = 2  # invented y coordinate
my_slope = 1  # invented slope value

def find_second_point(slope,x0,y0):
    # this function returns a point which belongs to the line that has the slope 
    # inserted by the user and that intercepts the point (x0,y0) inserted by the user
    q = y0 - (slope*x0)  # calculate q
    new_x = x0 + 10  # generate random x adding 10 to the intersect x coordinate
    new_y = (slope*new_x) + q  # calculate new y corresponding to random new_x created

    return new_x, new_y  # return x and y of new point that belongs to the line

# invoke function to calculate the new point
new_x, new_y = find_second_point(my_slope , x_intercept, y_intercept)

plt.figure(1)  # create new figure
plt.plot((x_intercept, new_x),(y_intercept, new_y), c='r', label='Segment')
plt.scatter(x_intercept, y_intercept, c='b', linewidths=3, label='Intercept')
plt.scatter(new_x, new_y, c='g', linewidths=3, label='New Point')
plt.legend()  # add legend to image

plt.show()
```

here is the image generated by the code:

[image: result image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer inspired by [kite.com](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-plot-a-line-of-best-fit-in-python):

```
plt.plot(x, s*x + i)
```

Reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=3        # intercept
s=2        # slope
x=np.linspace(1,10,50)      # from 1 to 10, by 50
plt.plot(x, s*x + i)        # abline
plt.show()
```

[image: 2x+3]

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple function by converting Slope-Intercept form to 2-Point Form.

```
def mxline(slope, intercept, start, end):
    y1 = slope*start + intercept
    y2 = slope*end + intercept
    plt.plot([start, end], [y1, y2])
```

Calling the function

```
mxline(m,c, 0, 20)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Graph of a Line]

Answer (score 0):

One can simply create a list with the line's equation obtained from a particular intercept and slope. Put those values in a list and plot it against any set of numbers you would like. For example- (Lr being the Linear regression model)

```
te= []
for i in range(11):
    te.append(Lr.intercept_ + Lr.coef_*i)
plt.plot(te, '--')
```

Gets the job done.