# How can I use matplotlib draw a scatter chart with slash grid？

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, scatter

How can I use matplotlib draw a scatter chart with slash grid？

Just like this：

Throughput and Efficiency for CNN

[image]

Comment: You can try to write some for loop iterating through the pair of x-y coordinates and have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104256/does-matplotlib-have-a-function-for-drawing-diagonal-lines-in-axis-coordinates)