# How to change the line color in seaborn linear regression jointplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

As described in the [seaborn API](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) the following code will produce a linear regression plot.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind='reg')
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

However, with a lot of data points the regression line is not really visible anymore. How can I change its color? I could not find a builtin seaborn command.

In case the line is in the background (i.e. behind the dots), I would also like to ask how to bring it to the front.

Comment: If seaborn returned the artists this would be very easy.  The best you can do, if there is not a knob in the function API, is to look at `g.lines` to try and guess which artist in the regression line and then do `ln.set_color('k')`

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately `AttributeError: 'JointGrid' object has no attribute 'lines'`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are a couple approaches, as mwaskom tactfully pointed out. You can pass arguments to the joint plot, but setting `color` there affects the whole scatterplot:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns#; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind='reg',
                  joint_kws={'color':'green'}) # Scatter and regression all green
```

[image]

Or pass a dictionary of line-plotting keywords through that dictionary of scatterplot keywords. I read `seaborn/linearmodels.py` to figure out where to do this, which was entertaining and informative in itself. Dict in dict:

```
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind='reg',
                  joint_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'cyan'}}) # Only regression cyan
```

[image]

Or you can access the line after it's been plotted and change it directly. This  depends on the regression line being the first line plotted, so could break with seaborn updates. It's also aesthetically/pedagogically different, as you don't recolor the uncertainty spread. It is a good way to get familiar with what the `JointGrid` object is and how else you might interact with it. (And maybe there are properties you can't set with the function call arguments, although I can't think of any.)

```
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind='reg')
regline = g.ax_joint.get_lines()[0]
regline.set_color('red')
regline.set_zorder(5)
```

[image]

Comment: This works but it would be better to just pass the color into the plot using the `joint_kws` option.

Comment: I think this is all the ways, @mwaskom. Anything else to document? :)

Comment: How can I get this output using the newest seaborn version ?

Comment: Now works with seaborn 0.11.1; the only change was to the last option, with the red  line.

Comment: Why it doesn't show me `pearsonr` and `p` values?

Comment: Seaborn used to do that automatically but doesn't any more, @Mehdi Abassi. (Thank you for pointing it out; I've updated the graphics.) It looks like best practice is to [calculate coefficients using statistical functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852244/how-to-get-the-numerical-fitting-results-when-plotting-a-regression-in-seaborn)  and add the text string yourself.