# Can I draw a regression line and show parameters using scatterplot with a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, scatter-plot

I would like to produce a Scatterplot from a Pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='one', y='two, title='Scatterplot')
```

Is there a Parameter I can send with the Statement, so it plots a Regression line and shows the Parameters of the fit?

something like:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='one', y='two', title='Scatterplot', Regression_line)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't think that there's such a paramter for DataFrame.plot(). However, you can easily achieve this using [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html). 
Just pass the pandas dataframe to [lmplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot) (assuming you have seaborn installed):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot(x='one',y='two',data=df,fit_reg=True)
```

Comment: great! it works for me.     Do you know how I can plot the Regression parameters on the Chart?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be not possible using lmplot as posted in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852244/how-to-get-the-numerical-fitting-results-when-plotting-a-regression-in-seaborn). However, you may have a look at this issue on [github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/207).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: is there a way in seaborn or lmplot where I could get the slope value of the regression line?

Comment: @PascaldB, very elegant!

Comment: Works like a charm. however, I have to set df.columns first, since x and y only accepts string.

Answer (score 19):

You can use sk-learn to get the regression line combined with scatter plot.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = df.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # iloc[:, 1] is the column of X
Y = df.iloc[:, 4].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # df.iloc[:, 4] is the column of Y
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]