# In jointplot when using seaborn, how to set another legend in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, legend, seaborn

1.I want to plot a joint distribution figure in 'hex' style with Seaborn, and I want to add a regression fitting using another data "all_data", and I want the Pearson 'r' and 'p-value' is calculated by 'all_data', but now it's calculated by 'data' which is used to draw 'hex' plot. How can I change the code to achieve my goal. What keywords should I add？

```
joint_kws={'gridsize':30}
g=sns.jointplot('nature','space',data,kind='hex',size=20,joint_kws= joint_kws)

sns.regplot(x='nature', y='space',data=all_data, ax=g.ax_joint, scatter=False,color='red')
```

[image]

2. Where can I find all the detailed keywords that control the size, font, location of legend and other things I can custom the fig by my own. Because I did not find some very detailed description about keywords in seaborn's document in their official website. Where can I get that? 
   Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to get the statistical info from the `regplot()` directly. The author of seaborn [has said this was not something he wanted to add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852265/1356000).

Instead, you will have to calculate the r-value yourself (i.e. using [`statsmodel`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/regression.html) or [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)), and write directly in the legend.

Concerning your second question, you can adjust the appearance of the legend generated by `jointplot()` using the `annot_kws=` parameter. This is a dictionnary of values that are passed to `legend()` upon legend creation. Therefore, to know the valid options, [refer to the documentation for `legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend).

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
annot_kws = {'prop':{'family':'monospace', 'weight':'bold', 'size':15}}
# you change the properties of the legend directly when calling jointplot
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="hex", annot_kws=annot_kws)
sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, ax=g.ax_joint, scatter=False, color='red')
# calculate r and p-value here
r = 0.9
p = 0.05
# if you choose to write your own legend, then you should adjust the properties then
phantom, = g.ax_joint.plot([], [], linestyle="", alpha=0)
g.ax_joint.legend([phantom],['r={:f}, p={:f}'.format(r,p)], **annot_kws)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for `ax_joint`, did not know you can use that to customize the legend.