# Is there a way to get the x-axis and y-axis values of my seaborn plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, regression, seaborn

I used seaborn library to get fit a regression line for my data. Then I also plotted the residual plot. I now need to see the histogram distribution of my residuals? How can I do that as I don't have the values plotted in the graph.

Here is my code:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(15,5))
sns.regplot(x = 'Radio',y='Sales',data=df_advertising,ax = axes[0])
sns.residplot(x = 'Radio',y='Sales',data=df_advertising,ax = axes[1])
```

How can I get the values of my residual plot so that I can plot the corresponding histogram to see the distribution.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated. I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite possible to get back the fit or the values (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852244/how-to-get-the-numerical-fitting-results-when-plotting-a-regression-in-seaborn)). It also makes sense that you know what you fit, and then plot the residuals. Below I use an example dataset:

```
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

df_advertising = pd.DataFrame({'Radio':np.random.randint(1,10,100)})
df_advertising['Sales'] = 3*df_advertising['Radio'] + np.random.normal(10,4,100)
```

We can plot it using seaborn:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,5))
sns.regplot(x = 'Radio',y='Sales',data=df_advertising,ax = axes[0])
sns.residplot(x = 'Radio',y='Sales',data=df_advertising,ax = axes[1])
```

[image]

seaborn uses statsmodels, so lets use that to fit and get the predictions:

```
mod = sm.OLS(df_advertising['Sales'],sm.add_constant(df_advertising['Radio']))
res = mod.fit()

test = df_advertising[['Radio']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('Radio')
predictions = res.get_prediction(sm.add_constant(test))
predictions = pd.concat([test,predictions.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)],axis=1)
predictions.head()

    Radio   mean    mean_se mean_ci_lower   mean_ci_upper   obs_ci_lower    obs_ci_upper
13  1   11.132902   0.700578    9.742628    12.523175   3.862061    18.403742
6   2   14.480520   0.582916    13.323742   15.637298   7.250693    21.710347
2   3   17.828139   0.478925    16.877728   18.778550   10.628448   25.027829
4   4   21.175757   0.399429    20.383104   21.968411   13.995189   28.356326
10  5   24.523376   0.360990    23.807002   25.239750   17.350827   31.695924
```

In the above, I create test to not duplicate the data points (since mine was counts). Now we have everything to plot. The residuals are simply under `resid` of the statsmodels object:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(15,5))

sns.scatterplot(x='Radio',y='Sales',ax=axes[0],data=df_advertising)
axes[0].plot(predictions['Radio'], predictions['mean'], lw=2)
axes[0].fill_between(x=predictions['Radio'],
                     y1=predictions['mean_ci_lower'],y2=predictions['mean_ci_upper'],
                     facecolor='blue', alpha=0.2)

sns.scatterplot(x='Radio',y='Sales',ax=axes[1],
                data=pd.DataFrame({'Radio':df_advertising['Radio'],
                                  'Sales':res.resid})
               )
axes[1].axhline(0, ls='--',color="k")

sns.distplot(res.resid,ax=axes[2],bins=20)
```

[image]