# How to draw a line on an image given the slope and the intercept coordinates (x, y) using Python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a slope of a line, and I have the x and y coordinates of the intercept that I want the line to go through. Essentially, I want the line to be displayed on the image itself.

The following is basically the only code I have so far (just the variables):

```
slope = 3
intercepts = [7, 10]
```

I want to use Python for this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into `matplotlib`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add line based on slope and intercept in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941226/how-to-add-line-based-on-slope-and-intercept-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @MrNobody33 No, because the intercept in this is the y. I want to do it so that a line goes through a point (x and y).

Comment: Actually the [4th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951876/13676202) take that into account. Take a look of it. @MichaelHansen

Comment: @MrNobody33 Yes, but I also want the line to intersect a specific point elsewhere on the graph (x and y)

Comment: you can custom that function @MichaelHansen

Answer (score 1):

You can custom [this answer from Tommaso Di Noto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951876/13676202):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x_intercept = 7  
y_intercept = 10 
my_slope = 3 

def find_second_point(slope,x0,y0):
    # this function returns two points which belongs to the line that has the slope 
    # inserted by the user and that intercepts the point (x0,y0) inserted by the user
    q = y0 - (slope*x0)  # calculate q
    new_x1 = x0 + random.randint(x0,x0+10)  
    new_y1 = (slope*new_x1) + q  
    new_x2 = x0 - random.randint(x0,x0+10)  
    new_y2 = (slope*new_x2) + q 
    return new_x1, new_y1, new_x2, new_y2   


new_x1, new_y1,new_x2, new_y2 = find_second_point(my_slope , x_intercept, y_intercept )

def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
print(slope(x_intercept,y_intercept, new_x1, new_y1))


plt.figure(1)  # create new figure
plt.plot((new_x2, new_x1),(new_y2, new_y1), c='r', label='Segment')
plt.scatter(x_intercept, y_intercept, c='b', linewidths=3, label='Intercept')
plt.scatter(new_x1, new_y1, c='g', linewidths=3, label='New Point 1')
plt.scatter(new_x2, new_y2, c='cyan', linewidths=3, label='New Point 2')
plt.legend()  # add legend to image

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
slope
3.0
```

[image]